# Please suggest some courses/ tutorial/books for creating soap request with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, soap

I have gone through almost all videos, blogs, which i could find related soap integrated with Nodejs, but couldn't find anything who's a complete beginner. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sample SOAP service

First of all, we will take a sample SOAP web service to consume from the Node environment. Let’s look at how this SOAP call might be structured.

**Request URL**

```
http://www.example.com/exampleapi
```

**XML Request Template**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUser>
      <UserId>123456</UserId>
    </GetUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**XML Response Template**

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body>
  <GetUserResponse>
    <Username>Clue Mediator</Username>
  </GetUserResponse>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

2. Add npm dependency

Here, we will use the easy-soap-request npm package to make SOAP requests easier via Node.js. Run the following command to install the npm dependency.

```
npm i easy-soap-request
```

3. Perform SOAP request

After successful installation of the npm package, perform the SOAP request by adding the following code snippets.

```
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
...
...
// Example data
const url = 'http://www.example.com/exampleapi';
const sampleHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
};
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUser>
      <UserId>123456</UserId>
    </GetUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
`;

// usage of module
(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest({ url: url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml: xml });
  console.log(response.body);
  /* Example output:
  <soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
  soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserResponse>
      <Username>Clue Mediator</Username>
    </GetUserResponse>
  </soap:Body>

  </soap:Envelope>
  */
})();
```

4. Output

When executing the above code, you will get the output specified in the response of the SOAP request. You will also receive the `headers` and `statusCode` along with the response from the `soapRequest`.

You can also check the same SOAP web service from the postman to verify it.

Comment: The url should be followed by ?wsdl or plain asmx? And how do I access the method inside it? It has 4 methods - getStudent, updateStudent, getCourse, updateCourse. I need to access getStudent which has headers username and pwd and payload as student id.